# app.publish components not getting copied after build

Tags: msbuild, cloud

I have a Release.proj file wich I am running during daily build. It should build my cloud service and then copy the contents of \bin\app.publish folder to another newly created folder. It is building the solution but the contents are not getting copied. I have tried using DependsOnTaret property also. It seems like timing issue. Follweing is what my Release.proj file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="PrepareRelease" ToolsVersion="4.0" >

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ReleaseFolderPath/>
    <ReleaseFolderPath Condition=" '$(OutDir)'=='' ">$(Configuration)\</ReleaseFolderPath>
    ......
........
.......
    <Configuration Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='' ">Release</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>

    <Package Include="..\AzureCloudService\bin\Release\app.publish\*.*"/>

  </ItemGroup>


  <Target Name="PrepareRelease">

    <MSBuild Targets="Publish" Projects="..\AzureService.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release;">
    </MSBuild>

    <MakeDir Directories="$(ReleaseFolderPath)\Package" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Package)" DestinationFolder="$(ReleaseFolderPath)\Package" />

      </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the files in "AzureCloudService\bin\Release\app.publish\" will be created during the MSBuild publish call, right? If so, just move your ItemGroup definition in the target:

```
<Target Name="PrepareRelease">

 <MSBuild Targets="Publish" Projects="..\AzureService.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release;" />
 <ItemGroup>
  <Package Include="..\AzureCloudService\bin\Release\app.publish\*.*"/>
 </ItemGroup>

 <MakeDir Directories="$(ReleaseFolderPath)\Package" />
 <Copy SourceFiles="@(Package)" DestinationFolder="$(ReleaseFolderPath)\Package" />

</Target>
```

When the ItemGroup element is outside a target, it will be defined before any target is called, which means if there is no file existing at the beginning of the build, it will be empty.